# Generating a table based on a list and a number of columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, xstring

Sometimes a table is used to compact a large number of items.

Example:

```
a b c d
e f g h
j k l
```

Instead of listing all items separately.

We want to define a command that eases the implementation of this (say you want to insert an item `i`, you don't want to do all the bookkeeping to make the items match again).

We want to define a command `\compacttable{cccc}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}` that displays such tables.

We tried the following definition:

```
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen,xstring,etoolbox}

\newcounter{col}
\newcommand{\compacttable}[2]{
    \setcounter{colc}{1}\StrLen{#1}[\imresl]
    \def\temp{}
    \foreach\tx in{#2}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\imresl}{\value{colc}}}{
        \setcounter{colc}{1}\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp \tx \\}
    }{
        \stepcounter{colc}\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp \tx & }
    }}
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \temp{}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

However the *MWE* fails to show any values:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen,xstring,etoolbox}
\newcounter{col}
\newcommand{\compacttable}[2]{
    \setcounter{colc}{1}\StrLen{#1}[\imresl]
    \def\temp{}
    \foreach\tx in{#2}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\imresl}{\value{colc}}}{
        \setcounter{colc}{1}\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp \tx \\}
    }{
        \stepcounter{colc}\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\temp \tx & }
    }}
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\compacttable{cccc}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}
\end{document}
```

We think this is due to the fact that `\tx` does not bind when we try to expand `\temp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without additional packages and using a token list which can easily add ans kind of TeX tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{col} \newcounter{maxcol} \newtoks\myTab
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\myTab\expandafter{\the\myTab#1}}
\newcommand\compacttable[2]{%
  \setcounter{col}{0}\setcounter{maxcol}{#1}%
  \myTab{\tabular{*#1c}}%                       Initial setting
  \compacttable@i#2,,\@nil}
\def\compacttable@i#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \stepcounter{col}%
  \ifnum\thecol<\themaxcol\addtabtoks{ #1 & }%  Default column
  \else \addtabtoks{#1 \\}\setcounter{col}{0}\fi% start new line
  \ifx\relax#2\relax \the\myTab\endtabular%     Output of list and \endtabular  
  \else \compacttable@i#2,#3\@nil\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\compacttable4{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}
\fbox{\compacttable3{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another question: why does `\myTab{\tabular{*#1c}\toprule}` doesn't work (with the `booktabs`) package?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful error description ... I have no problem with that code.

Comment: Sorry, We figured out it was a side effect of other commands. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

As you point out the problem is due to expansion. You *could* just do:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\temp\tx & }%
```

However, to improve readability defining an intermediate macro to reduce the multiple uses of `\expandafter` is possible as shown below. In addition, the code needs to have `%` after many of the lines ending in `{` and `}` to prevent spaces being inserted into the document.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor,ifthen,xstring}
\newcounter{colc}
\def\globalappendtomacro#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}%
}
\newcommand{\compacttable}[2]{%
    \setcounter{colc}{1}%
    \StrLen{#1}[\imresl]%
    \def\temp{}%
    \foreach\tx in{#2}{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\imresl}{\value{colc}}}{%
        \setcounter{colc}{1}%
        \expandafter\globalappendtomacro\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\tx \\}%
    }{%
        \stepcounter{colc}%
        \expandafter\globalappendtomacro\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\tx &}%
     }}%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
      \temp
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\framebox{\compacttable{cccc}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's an `expl3` implementation; save the input in a sequence annd do a mapping; if the column count is equal to the specified number of columns, add `\\` and zero the column counter, otherwise just add `&`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\compacttable}{ m m }
 {
  \commusoft_compact_table:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__commusoft_col_int
\tl_new:N \l__commusoft_table_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__commusoft_input_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \commusoft_compact_table:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__commusoft_table_body_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__commusoft_col_int
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__commusoft_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__commusoft_input_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__commusoft_col_int
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__commusoft_col_int == #1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__commusoft_table_body_tl { ##1 \\ }
      \int_zero:N \l__commusoft_col_int
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__commusoft_table_body_tl { ##1 & }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \l__commusoft_table_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\compacttable{4}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}

\compacttable{5}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more straightforward implementation using features not available at the time the answer was first written.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\compacttable}{ m m }
 {
  \commusoft_compact_table:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__commusoft_input_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \commusoft_compact_table:nn
 {
  % split the input at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__commusoft_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  % define an auxiliary function to store the number of columns
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__commusoft_item:nn
   {% ##1 is the current index, ##2 is the current item
    ##2
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { #1 } == 0 } { \\ } { & }
   }
  % make the table by mapping the sequence
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__commusoft_input_seq \__commusoft_item:nn
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\compacttable{4}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l}

\compacttable{5}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m}

\end{document}
```